# cleaning is aborted and paused in kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

I looked into `log-cleaner.log` of one of the kafka broker and observed messages reading -

`[2019-12-16 08:45:25,443] INFO The cleaning for partition test1-0 is aborted and paused (kafka.log.LogCleaner)
 [2019-12-16 08:45:25,444] INFO The cleaning for partition reddyvel-test1-0 is aborted (kafka.log.LogCleaner)`.

What does this mean and why cleaning is aborted for the partition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This message is coming from Kafka's `LogCleaner` component.

The cleaner is responsible for removing obsolete records from logs which has the `compact` retention strategy applied.

The difference between the two are -

[**abortAndPauseCleaning**](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/92dd337688a519e88f2b206fb506f3cd3aad14d2/core/src/main/scala/kafka/log/LogCleanerManager.scala#L281):

```
Abort the cleaning of a particular partition if it's in progress, and pause any future cleaning of this partition.
 This call blocks until the cleaning of the partition is aborted and paused.
 1. If the partition is not in progress, mark it as paused.
 2. Otherwise, first mark the state of the partition as aborted.
 3. The cleaner thread checks the state periodically and if it sees the state of the partition is aborted, it
    throws a LogCleaningAbortedException to stop the cleaning task.
 4. When the cleaning task is stopped, doneCleaning() is called, which sets the state of the partition as paused.
 5. abortAndPauseCleaning() waits until the state of the partition is changed to paused.
 6. If the partition is already paused, a new call to this function
    will increase the paused count by one.
```

[**abortCleaning**](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/92dd337688a519e88f2b206fb506f3cd3aad14d2/core/src/main/scala/kafka/log/LogCleanerManager.scala#L261):

```
Abort the cleaning of a particular partition, if it's in progress. This call blocks until the cleaning of the partition is aborted.
This is implemented by first abortAndPausing and then resuming the cleaning of the partition.
```

You can read more about the Log Cleaner and how Kafka compaction works on Cloudurable [blog post](http://cloudurable.com/blog/kafka-architecture-log-compaction/index.html).

Comment: Why is partition cleaning aborted in the first place?

Comment: @Markiv - `If a log is truncated while it is being cleaned the cleaning of that log is aborted.` [source](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/core/src/main/scala/kafka/log/LogCleaner.scala#L65).

You can debug it by enabling the `kafka.log.LogCleaner`, `kafka.log.Cleaner`, and
`kafka.log.LogCleanerManager` loggers at the DEBUG level will output information
about the status of these threads. This will include information about each partition
being compacted, including the size and number of messages in each.

Mind to share the configuration of the topic and your version?